# How to display thumbnail and excerpt of a page on homepage?

Tags: pages, homepage, frontpage

How to display attached thumbnail and excerpt (about 200 words) of a page on homepage?

```
<?php 
$page_data = get_page( 401 ); // Get page ID 401
echo '<h3>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h3>';
echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content);
?>
```

I don't know how to display attached image as thumbnail. May be i use mb_substr php function to cut the content to the excerpt.

Sorry, my english is not good. :)
Thanks for help!

Comment: i've tried with get_page function. But i can't get the page excerpt & attached thumbnail with it. tks for help.

Comment: Please edit the question and paste the code that you used.

Comment: i've edit and update the question. thanks all very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php $post_id = 50; // assign post id
                $queried_post = get_page($post_id);
                if(is_home()) {  ?>
                <div class='product_title'><h3><a href="<?php echo get_page_link($post_id); ?>"><?php echo $queried_post->post_title;  ?></a></h3></div>                    
                <div class='product_image_location'><?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $post_id); ?></div>
                <div class='description_product'>
                <?php echo $queried_post->post_content;  ?></div>
            <?php  } ?>
```

Comment: You should really _start_ with the `is_home()` check. Otherwise you would send the extra query on each request.